# Neo4j - Filter on the basis of multiple types of relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If

```
match(d:person)-[r]-(e:person)
```

and r could be of many types such as `KNOWS, FRIEND_OF, LIKES, DISLIKES`
and I would like to filter only those relationships of `KNOWS` and `DISLIKES`, then how should I express this in cypher?

I know that for a single relationship type, it goes like this

```
match(d:person)-[r:KNOWS]-(e:person)
```

but I would like to do it for multiple relationship types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have

```
MATCH (d:person)-[r:KNOWS|DISLIKES|RELTYPE3|RELTYPE4]-(e:person)
```

Answer (score 0):

One can do the following

```
match(d:person)-[r]-(e:person) where type(r) in ['KNOWS', 'DISLIKES']
```

Also, watch out for queries like this

```
match(d:person)-[r]-(e:person) where (d)-[:KNOWS]-(e) or (d)-[:DISLIKES]-(e)
```

In my experience, these will run for long and potentially blow your neo4j memory